# How to push ID into form in popup using ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a delete method where first I ask the user If he/she wants to delete the record. If user clicks yes, I will delete the record using the form but in order to delete it , I must send the ID inside the modal. How can I do that ? If I use foreach for modal it says something like too many request and tries to delete all the records, not the only one I ask.

```
<br />
<a asp-controller="Banner" asp-action="Create" style="float:right"  class="btn btn-success">Create</a></td>
</br>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Redirect Url</th>
    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Banners)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.RedirectUrl</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="Banner" asp-action="Update" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Update</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="@item.Id" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Delete
                </button>

                <a asp-controller="Banner" asp-action="Delete" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#exampleModal" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Deletee</a>
            </td>    
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Banner", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal",  enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record? </p>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    bool value = true;

    if (value == true)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new DeleteBannertByIdCommand(id));
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["error"] = "Something went wrong";
    }

    return Redirect("index");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to set the value of a hidden `input` element inside your modal form when a delete button is clicked.

```
<!-- ... -->
<button data-id="@item.Id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary delete-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Delete
</button>
<!-- ... -->

<!-- ... -->
<div class="modal-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Banner", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="delete-input" name="id" />
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record? </p>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<!-- ... -->

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        const onDeleteButtonClicked = function () {
            var deleteInput = document.getElementById('delete-input');
            deleteInput.value = this.dataset.id;
        };

        const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-button');

        deleteButtons.forEach(function (deleteButton) {
            deleteButton.onclick = onDeleteButtonClicked;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This works thank you so much but modal only has a  modal-body and this is causing to opening the modal when page is loaded. When I add the <div class =modal fade> back , I can't click to any button. Any idea how can I fix this ?

Comment: In my answer I only included the parts of your code that need changes. In your actual code you should have the whole modal like you had it before. I didn't include it to make answer shorter and easier to understand which changes are needed.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing and adding to the modal. Thank you so much for your help , I've learned a lot.